# How to get Element name in wpf using linq to xml concept?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

```
<Contacts>
       <Node>
           <ID>123</ID>
           <Name>ABC</Name>
       </Node>
       <Node>
           <ID>124</ID>
           <Name>DEF</Name>
       </Node>
</Contacts>
```

Here i want to get Element name(Tag Name) such as **Contacts**,**Node**,**ID**,**Name** using linq to xml concept.What should i do for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xml = @"<Contacts>
                    <Node>
                        <ID>123</ID>
                        <Name>ABC</Name>
                    </Node>
                    <Node>
                        <ID>124</ID>
                        <Name>DEF</Name>
                    </Node>
            </Contacts>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var namelist = xdoc.Descendants()
                    .Select(i => i.Name.ToString())
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

You will get:

```
{"Contacts","Node","ID","Name"}
```

If you want to get the name list of first node

```
var nodes = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Node"));
var firstNode = nodes.First();
var namelist = firstNode.Descendants()
                    .Select(i => i.Name.ToString())
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: The above code is ok.if I want to get child of <Node> then what should i do ?